# Inserting row into table and then updating it in sum of each column using ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcpy, cursor

My problem is the following:

- I have a table with an unknown number of columns (n)
- Use arcpy.ListFields create a list of columns and generates Field name list
- Then, using arcpy.da.InsertCursor create a new row at the end of the table ...

for example

```
  fieldNameList = []     
  fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc, "*")

  for field in fields:
     if field.type in ("Double", "Integer", "Single"): 
        fieldNameList.append(field.name) 

 cur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, fieldNameList)
 for x in xrange(-1, 0):
     cur.insertRow((SUM_FIELD1, SUM_FIELD2...SUM_FIELD n ))       ?????????!!!!
 del cur
```

I do not know how to calculate the sum for each column and then the result to update in the created row. The sum should be separately calculated for each column ...

Comment: Is it the sum of the preceding values? You might need to use a search cursor to get those values and sum them.

Comment: Your logic is a bit off.  You'd be better off calculating the sums via a `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` query, then once you have the sums bundled in a dictionary by column name, insert a row with the sums.

Comment: That's how I'd do it Vince. Perhaps you could put that in as an answer.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Feel free to run with it (I'm on a code deadline)

Comment: Yes, the sum of the previous value. I am an absolute beginner in using python. Can you give me an example? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use Dictionaries (I don't fully understand them), however the new row can also be a list. Start by compiling a list of the sums and then insert that.

```
fieldNameList = []
values = [] # store the sum values here.
fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc, "*")

# get the OID/FID field name to skip
desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
if desc.hasOID:
    OIDname = desc.OIDFieldName.upper()
else:
    OIDname = ""

for field in fields:
    if field.name.upper() != OIDname: # skip the OID/FID field.
        if field.type in ("Double", "Integer", "Single"):
            # sum each suitable field, but not the NULL ones - they would be bad
            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,field.name,field.name + " is not NULL") as sCur:
                thisValue = 0
                for row in sCur:
                    thisValue += row[0]
                values.append(thisValue) # this will be the inserted row
            fieldNameList.append(field.name) 

with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, fieldNameList) as cur:
    cur.insertRow(values)
```

This does of course mean that you'll read through the rows for each numeric field.. but that also includes OID/FID - that's bad! the values for OID/FID can't be modified so best to skip that one. Also shape_area, shape_length are read-only but this looks like tabular data so I wont worry about that (this time).

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much @Michael Miles-Stimson

Comment: One more question ... If an unknown number of rows and columns, how to calculate the following:

(X1 / SUMi) + (X2 / SUMi) + (Xn / SUMi)

where is:

X1, X2, Xn : Single values in the cells in the column "i"...

Of course, in the context of the preceding code?

Thanks

Comment: For followup questions I think you should [ask a new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I think this has left the realm of GIS and entered Spreadsheets 101.

Comment: That's always an option @Vince, export table to an Excel format (csv, Excel, txt) and do the calc there. I'd be the first to admit to doing that - after all isn't why I have Excel installed? I'm with PolyGeo, I think that a different calc, especially one that is so fundamentally different, deserves a fresh question. Refer to this post in the new question for background information.

Comment: Thank you guys. Of course, this problem is easily solved in Excel but I'm learning the basics of programming in arcpy and python, trying to understand some of the basics.